# DependencyProperty.UnsetValue appears when using a IMultiValueConverter

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, converters, imultivalueconverter

I created a simple Converter to concatenate the text of four TextBoxes in my WPF app.

Here is the Converter:

```
public class FourString:IMultiValueConverter
{
     public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
   {

       return string.Format("{0}{1}{2}{3}", values[0], values[1], values[2], values[3]);

   }
   public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
   {


       return new object[] {  };
   }

}
```

in Xaml I use this code:

```
<local:FourString x:Key="converter"/>


  <TextBox  Grid.ColumnSpan="4"  Margin="95,7.5,71.25,3.75" Name="CodeBoatTxt" >
                            <TextBox.Text>
                                <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource converter}" >
                                    <Binding ElementName="CountryStringaTxt" Path="Text" />
                                    <Binding ElementName="CityStringaTxt" Path="Text" />
                                    <Binding ElementName="ServiceStringaTxt" Path="Text" />
                                    <Binding ElementName="DurationStringaTxt" Path="Text" />

                                </MultiBinding>
                            </TextBox.Text>
                        </TextBox>
```

When in debug, this error appears in the CodeBoatTxt textbox: "DependecyProperty.UnsetValue".

What is wrong with my converter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`DependencyProperty.UnsetValue` is passed into the converter when a `Binding` is valid, but does not have its value set yet. I would check the `Binding`s comprising your `MultiBinding` in isolation and ensure they are correct.

Comment: HI Kent,
you have right i check out my code and found out a error for my distraction.
Thanks .

Cheers